# Transform Lines to Polygons QGIS - FEMA SFHA

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, polygonize

I am very new to GIS. Using QGIS LTR 3.22

I have downloaded the FEMA SFHA Shape files from FEMA's website. There are a few layers but the specific one I am working with is the S_FLD_HAZ_LN layer.

https://msc.fema.gov/portal/advanceSearch#searchresultsanchor

( Search State - New York, County - New York County, Community - New York, City Of )

( Click Effective Products, NFHL Data-County)

[image]

I want to convert these lines to polygons

I have tried Lines to Polygons

[image]

It doesn't work. I have tried Polygonize

[image]

I have used v.clean as well and then polygonize and that did not work.

It would be ideal if I could get the polygons to look like this

[image]

with the blue being the wanted polygons.